# JQuery Post - Why I can't see response?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**This is my HTML PAGE**

I want to send some values with ajax then I want to get them with ajax response but I can't see any character in my div which called with `id=result` . Where is the problem?

```
   <html>
    <head>

     <!-- JQuery v1.8.2 -->
    <script src="theme/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">

        <input type="text" id="title"/><br>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="content"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" id="gonderBtn" name="gonderBtn" />

        <div id="result"></div>

    </div>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">     
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("#gonderBtn").click(function(){
            var title   = $("title").val();
            var content = $("content").val();


         $.ajax({
             url: "deneme_action.php", 
             dataType: "html",
             type: 'POST',
             data: {
                 title: title,
                 content: content
             },
             success: function(data){ 
               $("result").html(data); 

             }
          });
        });
    });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

**deneme_action.php**

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["gonderBtn"])){

    $result = "Sonuc:".$_POST["title"];
     echo  "Selam:".$result;
}

else{
    echo "no post";
}


?>
```

Comment: There is no error and no output on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have a tag with `class="result"` but you have a tag with `id="result"`.
Either change the jQuery selector to:

```
$("#result").html(data);
```

Or the div tag to:

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

and selector to:

```
$(".result").html(data);
```

And you are not sending `gonderBtn` with the POST - fix it too:

```
$("#gonderBtn").click(function(){
        var title   = $("#title").val();
        var content = $("#content").val();
        var gonderBtn = $(this).val();


     $.ajax({
         url: "deneme_action.php", 
         dataType: "html",
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
             title: title,
             content: content,
             gonderBtn: gonderBtn,
         },
```

I've also fixed the selectors for input and textarea too.

Comment: Changing that div tag to `class="result"` would mean you also need to change `$("#result").html(data);` to `$(".result").html(data);`

Comment: I think problem is at PHP side. When I click button response comes from else statement. So response is = "no post" see else statement on my question pls

Comment: Ok, Thanks!!. It is working now. Also I have understood everything clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting your `#result` div properly, add a `#` before

```
$("#result").html(data);
```

the same goes for all your selectors

```
var title   = $("#title").val();
var content = $("#content").val();
```

Since your ajaxing your form you'll have to manually pass your button parameter, although an ajax parameter would be more appropriate.

```
data: {
   title: title,
   content: content,
   gonderBtn: 'gonderBtn'
},
```

Comment: I replaced them with yours but still I cant see anything on screen

Answer (score 1):

```
var title   = $("title").val();
var content = $("content").val();
```

should be

```
var title   = $("#title").val();
var content = $("#content").val();
```

You will also need to change:

```
$("result").html(data);
```

to

```
$("#result").html(data);
```

You should also wrap your inputs in a form.

Edit:
You might want to give your button input a value.

```
<input type="submit" id="gonderBtn" name="gonderBtn" value="go!" />
```

Edit 2:
You will also need to give your html elements a name.

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"/><br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="content" name="content"></textarea><br>
```

Comment: Are you sure about wraping inputs in a from?

Comment: Technically you don't need it but its invalid html without it

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
echo  "Selam:"+$result;
```

Here the plus operator is an error so the php script is not returning anything.

Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) link that documents the use of + operator in php.

Comment: what did you replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo  "Selam:"+$result;
```

In php use "." to concatenate strings.

```
 echo  "Selam:".$result;
```